# PL/SQL Cursor If No Data & Output

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_data
IS
cursor c1 is 
select 
  e.id
from 
  table1 e 
where 
  id IN (select id from table1)
  and id in (select id from table2);
BEGIN
FOR ed in c1
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ed.id||ed.name);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When i execute this PL/SQL , it output as

14Andrew R. Smith

I want to ask is how do i make it output as a normal result like this with the formating etc.. and also

Below is what happen if i run the select statement directly with at terminal

```
        ID NAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        14 Andrew R. Smith
```

**First Question:**
How to make my DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE same as what appear on terminal. like the ID then below is the ID data , and NAME etc.

**Next Question:**

I want to ask is

how do i do a output that if cursor is empty or no result, i DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("NO RECORDS");

**Thanks for all help!!**

**Update:**

I did this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_data
IS
cursor c1 is 
select 
  e.id
from 
  table1 e 
where 
  id IN (select id from table1)
  and id in (select id from table2);
BEGIN
FOR ed in c1
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ed.id||ed.name);

 if c1%notfound then
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Okay');
  end if;

END LOOP;

END;
```

But it does not **print Okay** when no record is fetch from the PL/SQL. I added the c1%notfound to after END LOOP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see columns name you have to add before your loop one more line:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col1 col2 ...');
```

I think this is only one way to do that.

Below code shows how to check cursor:

```
if c1%notfound then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO RECORDS');
end if;
```

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/attributes.php) you can find more information about cursor attributes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_data
IS
id number;
name varchar;
cursor c1 is 
select 
  e.id,e.name
from 
  table1 e 
where 
  id IN (select id from table1)
  and id in (select id from table2);
BEGIN

   open c1;
   fetch c1 into id,name;

   if c1%notfound then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK')
      EXIT; 
   else   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(id||name)
   end if;

   close c1;

END;
```

Comment: Hi there, i try put this if c1%notfound then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO RECORDS');
end if; at after my END LOOP and it give me some error like *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "USER1.VERIFY_EMPLOYEE", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: You have to put the code inside the loop (before `end lopp`).

Comment: I updated my question with the update, i did put inside, but it does not print anything. The question is if there is no record fetch, it won't even go in the loop i suppose. but anyway i added as what you mention and it does not print the message "okay".

Comment: You have to change your loop to cursor statement as in example. I edited the post, you can see my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using dbms_output you won't get any headings like in a normal sql select statement.

So the only way I know is printing your own headings.
And if you initialize a counter before the loop and increase it inside the loop, you can check after the loop if there was a result. Then you can print a message like "NO RECORDS" if you want.